# Update multiple table without knowing the table name (due to a chain of Foreign key relationship)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update one field for a few rows in one table (say, Table_A). However, I'm getting an error message saying `conflict with the Foreign Key Constraint in Table_B`.

So, I tried to update Table_B as well, turns out Table_B has `Foreign Key Constraint` with Table_C and Table_D; again, I tried to update Table_C and D, turns out they are conflicting with table_E, F, G, H, I, J, K etc. etc. and on and on.

I was told that such "chain" can go up to 20+ tables.

Additionally, I do not have access to the database schema, thus it is extremely difficult for me to determine which `field` in which table is the `foreign key` for the other table.

Currently, all I can do is manually checking each table, all the way from A-Z by using `select *` statement from the table that is showing in the error message. I'm wondering if there is any alternative to update these specific fields all across tables A till (whichever the last table) directly?

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Why can't you see the table schema? Can you query the foreign keys DMV? select *
from sys.foreign_key_columns

Comment: It gives me `constraint object id`, `constraint column id`, `parent object id`, `parent column id` etc. just a bunch of numbers. How do I determine from that?

Comment: Well you have to start with parent_object_id. That will be the ObjectID for the table you  are starting with. Then the referenced_object_id is the object_id for the table with a foreign key. The parent and referenced column_ids can be determined by looking at sys.columns. It is not a simple query to put together to find all foreign key constraints related to a given table. This is (or at least can be) recursive. This is why it is much easier if you see the schema of your database.

Comment: Here is the BOL entry for that DMV. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186306.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the names of the tables and columns in your foreign keys

```
SELECT 
  OBJECT_NAME(fk.[constraint_object_id])    AS [foreign_key_name]
 ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fk.[parent_object_id]) AS [parent_schema_name]
 ,OBJECT_NAME(fk.[parent_object_id])        AS [parent_table_name]
 ,pc.[name]                                 AS [parent_column_name]
 ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fk.[parent_object_id]) AS [referenced_schema_name]
 ,OBJECT_NAME(fk.[referenced_object_id])    AS [referenced_table_name]
 ,rc.[name]                                 AS [referenced_column_name]
FROM [sys].[foreign_key_columns] fk
INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] pc ON 
  pc.[object_id] = fk.[parent_object_id] AND
  pc.[column_id] = fk.[parent_column_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] rc ON
  rc.[object_id] = fk.[referenced_object_id] AND
  rc.[column_id] = fk.[referenced_column_id]
```

How to best display and analyze the connection graph is a more subjective matter and will depend on the complexity of your schema.